PostgreSQL connection string in Azure App Service
I'm trying to get my connection string from Azure App Services to work. I'm using PostgreSQL. I have set the connection string in the config settings. Currently its set to;
Name: DefaultConnection
Value: Server=some-database.postgres.database.azure.com;Database={MyDatabaseName};Port=5432;User Id={myUserId};Password={MyPassword;Ssl Mode=Require;
Type: Custom
I have tried setting the type to custom as well as Postgres. I read that there are some issues with the prefixing of the PG connection strings.
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36123
This is where I pass the conn string:
var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDatabase(connectionString);
  public static IServiceCollection AddDatabase(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString)
  {
      services.AddSingleton<IDbConnectionFactory>(_ => new NpgsqlConnectionFactory(connectionString));
      services.AddSingleton<DbInitializer>();
      return services;
  }

I have tried hardcoding the connection string, exactly as it is written in App Services. THAT works. I'm at my wits end here as I'm also setting other secrets in Application Settings, and they work fine. For example, I fetch a JWT Secret
var jwtTokenSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JWT_TOKEN_SECRET");
and this works absolutely fine. Any ideas? I'm sure I've missed something very obvious. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. This is my first post on SO, so if I've missed something in the description, please let me know.
Tried changing the database connection string type from Postgres to Custom. Tried hardcoding the value and that worked. Tried prefixing the con string directly, as
var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CUSTOMCONNSTR_DefaultConnection");

Welcome to  SO! You have not mentioned what is the error you are encountering, are you not getting the value of the env variable? is it blank or not completely the value you have set to ? have you tried to Log it and saw in the Log Stream or app insight ?

Here is the doc page that gives the sample code to connect using the Connection String authentication type.

Hi Anand! Thank you! What a huge miss from my part, I apologize. The error was that the connectionString wasn't initialized, and thus the connection to the database failed. I realize logging the actual value of the connection string would've been the most straight forward way but unfortunately I got nothing  substantial from the Log Stream or app insight. But that's most likely due to the fact that I'm new to Azure and probably haven't set up my logging correctly.
In the end I solved it by setting the connection string as an app setting instead of a con string.

In the doc you linked, is "AZURE_POSTGRESQL_" a prepend to the variable name "CONNECTIONSTRING"? If that's the case then my syntax was wrong from the get go, but if "AZURE_POSTGRESQL_CONNECTIONSTRING" is supposed to represent the exact name of the environment variable name stored in Azure then that's where my confusion is coming from. I've made 100% sure that the environment names match and the value itself, copied from said variable, works if hard coded. But yeah, without logging the value that's coming through it's a guessing game of what's going wrong, and that's on me to implement better.
